# Converting HTML Code to human understandable code

Tags: php, html, character-encoding

Most of my content in the database is recorded in this way. How can this be translated into HTML code structure?

```
&#x3C;div class=&#x22;main_title mb-4&#x22;&#x3E;n&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x3C;h2&#x3E;New Arrival&#x3C;/h2&#x3E;n&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x3C;span&#x3E;Products&#x3C;/span&#x3E;n&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x3C;p&#x3E;Cum doctus civibus efficiantur in imperdiet deterruisset.&#x3C;/p&#x3E;n&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x3C;/div&#x3E;n&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x3C;div class=&#x22;isotope_filter&#x22;&#x3E;n&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x3C;ul&#x3E;&#x3C;li&#x3E;&#x3C;a href=&#x22;http://www.example.com/index-2.html#0&#x22; id=&#x22;all&#x22; data-filter=&#x22;*&#x22;&#x3E;All&#x3C;/a&#x3E;&#x3C;/li&#x3E;&#x3C;li&#x3E;&#x3C;a href=&#x22;http://www.example.com/index.html#0&#x22; id=&#x22;popular&#x22; data-filter=&#x22;.popular&#x22;&#x3E;Popular&#x3C;/a&#x3E;&#x3C;/li&#x3E;&#x3C;li&#x3E;&#x3C;a href=&#x22;http://www.example.com/index-2.html#0&#x22; id=&#x22;sale&#x22; data-filter=&#x22;.sale&#x22;&#x3E;Sale&#x3C;/a&#x3E;&#x3C;/li&#x3E;&#x3C;/ul&#x3E;n&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x3C;/div&#x3E;
```

Convert to:

```
<div class="main_title mb-4">n <h2>New Arrival</h2>n <span>Products</span>n <p>Cum doctus civibus efficiantur in imperdiet deterruisset.</p>n </div>n <div class="isotope_filter">n <ul><li><a href="http://www.example.com/index-2.html#0" id="all" data-filter="*">All</a></li><li><a href="http://www.example.com/index.html#0" id="popular" data-filter=".popular">Popular</a></li><li><a href="http://www.example.com/index-2.html#0" id="sale" data-filter=".sale">Sale</a></li></ul>n </div>
```

Comment: Why is your content stored that way in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`html_entity_decode()`](https://php.net/html_entity_decode):

```php
$str = '&#x3C;div class=&#x22;main_title mb-4&#x22;&#x3E;n&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x3C;h2&#x3E;New Arrival&#x3C;/h2&#x3E;n&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x3C;span&#x3E;Products&#x3C;/span&#x3E;n&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x3C;p&#x3E;Cum doctus civibus efficiantur in imperdiet deterruisset.&#x3C;/p&#x3E;n&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x3C;/div&#x3E;n&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x3C;div class=&#x22;isotope_filter&#x22;&#x3E;n&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x3C;ul&#x3E;&#x3C;li&#x3E;&#x3C;a href=&#x22;http://www.example.com/index-2.html#0&#x22; id=&#x22;all&#x22; data-filter=&#x22;*&#x22;&#x3E;All&#x3C;/a&#x3E;&#x3C;/li&#x3E;&#x3C;li&#x3E;&#x3C;a href=&#x22;http://www.example.com/index.html#0&#x22; id=&#x22;popular&#x22; data-filter=&#x22;.popular&#x22;&#x3E;Popular&#x3C;/a&#x3E;&#x3C;/li&#x3E;&#x3C;li&#x3E;&#x3C;a href=&#x22;http://www.example.com/index-2.html#0&#x22; id=&#x22;sale&#x22; data-filter=&#x22;.sale&#x22;&#x3E;Sale&#x3C;/a&#x3E;&#x3C;/li&#x3E;&#x3C;/ul&#x3E;n&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x3C;/div&#x3E;';

echo html_entity_decode($str);
```

output:

```
<div class="main_title mb-4">n              <h2>New Arrival</h2>n               <span>Products</span>n              <p>Cum doctus civibus efficiantur in imperdiet deterruisset.</p>n           </div>n         <div class="isotope_filter">n               <ul><li><a href="http://www.example.com/index-2.html#0" id="all" data-filter="*">All</a></li><li><a href="http://www.example.com/index.html#0" id="popular" data-filter=".popular">Popular</a></li><li><a href="http://www.example.com/index-2.html#0" id="sale" data-filter=".sale">Sale</a></li></ul>n            </div>
```

Comment: Thank you - the letter "n" appeared between sentences, what could be the reason for this? [Image](https://ibb.co/xhPHhHD)

Comment: Look at your source: `main_title mb-4&#x22;&#x3E;n&#x9;`, you can see `&#x3E;` (`>`), then `n`, then `&#x9;` (`\t`). It can be caused by encoding.

Comment: Is there any way to clear this? I try this but doesn't work `preg_replace("/\r|\n/", "", $text);`

Comment: try `str_replace(">n\t",'>', html_entity_decode($str))`